# Ext.Loader Synchronously loading. Should I Ext.require() all my stores?

Tags: extjs

I have 20 Stores in my app. And i'm tunning & minifying my App with sencha build.
While debugging I saw a lot of [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading warnings:

```
[Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'MyApp.store.Store1'; consider adding Ext.require('MyApp.store.Store1') above Ext.onReady
```

My question is, should I include **once** all my stores with Ext.requires(['MyApp.store.Store1' ... StoreN]) before Ext.application({ .. }); or should I include only requires: ['MyApp.store.StoreX'] in the Class that uses that store.

Comment: For development it doesn't matter. For production - all should be minified in a single file

Comment: But for production, do this warnings matter?

Comment: [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'MyApp.store.Store1'; consider adding Ext.require('MyApp.store.Store1') above Ext.onReady

Comment: add it to `requires` property of the class that uses them http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-requires

Comment: In case of my stores, I use them repeatedly in many classes. Isn't Requiring them only once at the begining of the App better than requiring them repeatedly on every file that uses them ? (this is my main concern)

Comment: is having a warning better than not having a warning? PS: you actually could check if the `Ext.Loader` is enabled and not load otherwise (in production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could manage to get rid of all the warnings without going through every file and analyze it's store dependencies, was to add Ext.require(['MyApp.store.Store1' ... 'StoreN'].

**Stores are use widely in my App, thats why I thought that requiring them ONCE was better and more practical than requiring them in every file that uses them.**

If you see any downsides in this approach please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Stores should be placed in the [stores configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-stores) of Ext.app.Application or specific controllers.

Then they are not only loaded at the correct time but also registered with StoreManager, so that you can access them with [controller.getStore(storeId)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-getStore).

Comment: Thanks Christoph. I already had the stores: [...] config in my Application, and still see the warnings. I'm using extjs 4.0.7

Comment: "Stores should be placed in the stores configuration of Ext.app.Application or specific controllers." --- if only you use the MVC layout proposed by ExtJS. Which isn't ideal and optional

Comment: I'm using the MVC layout, and I already had the stores in the stores  configuration of Ext.app.Application. 

The only way I could manage to get rid of all the warnings without going through every file and analyze it's store dependencies, was to add Ext.require(['MyApp.store.Store1' ... 'StoreN'].

**Stores are use widely in my App, thats why I thought that requiring them ONCE was better and more practical than requiring them in every file that uses them.**

If you see any downsides in this approach please let me know!

Comment: as zerkms said, there is no problem with your approach.